# How to read and modify pixels according to a color table in WebGL

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, fragment-shader

I am stuck in WebGL with a requirement where I have to read pixel value from a color table and render to the texture.

I have already done it successfully in HTML5 2D canvas.
Here is the snippet for the same:

**Reading a color table on page load:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/resources/js/libs/luts/ProposedColorTable.bmp', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arrayBuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var decryptedLUT = this.response;
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(decryptedLUT.length);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var index = 0; index < decryptedLUT.length; index++) {
        bufView[index] = decryptedLUT.charCodeAt(index);
    }
    window.colorBufView = bufView;
};
```

**Logic to modify existing canvas w.r.t the above loaded color table:**

```
//Get Default Image data
var imageDataArr = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
//generate PsuedoColor
var numPixels = width * height * 4;
for (var i = 0, idImg = 0; idImg < numPixels;) {
    var position = imageBuffer[i++];
    imageDataArr.data[idImg++] = colorBufView [position++]; // red
    imageDataArr.data[idImg++] = colorBufView [position++]; // green
    imageDataArr.data[idImg++] = colorBufView [position]; // blue
    imageDataArr.data[idImg++] = 255; // alpha
}
//logic to update the image
context.putImageData(imageDataArr, 0, 0);
```

Now I know that for WebGL reading of color table will be via AJAX, but the loading the pixel value will be through passing the color table as a *Typed Array* to **Fragment Shader**, but I am not sure of the logic of what to write inside fragment shader, can anybody help me on how to read the pixel value according the logic that I did for 2D canvas as shown above.

Comment: yes I saw that , it seems like a duplicate , but the jsfiddle links given by you as answer over there are not working anymore.  Could you please check ? Also, I am following your image processing tutorial for multiple image processing @ !(http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html)[here], just wanted to say thanks for the nice tutorials

Comment: Also ,as you could see my snippet above, I am taking a ALPHA channel and creating RGBA values out of it . Is the fragment shader written by you over there will do that? `float index = texture2D(u_image, v_texcoord).a;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_palette, vec2(index, 0.5));`

Comment: I put the samples inline in that answer so they work again. And yes, that's what it's doing over there.